# Iteration of dict with key and List of values in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, for-loop

I have dictionary in python with key as 'string' and value as list of integers. Iterating the dict with key and value and if delete the value in the list if it does not meet some conditions.
Iteration does not properly.

For example,

```
my_dict = {"emp_id":[100,200]}

for emp,ids in my_dict.iteritems():
    print "Emp :",emp
    for id in ids:
        print "Id :",id
        if not id > 1000:
            my_dict.get(emp).remove(id)
            continue
```

Output :

```
Emp : emp_id
Id : 100
```

It does not iterate the second value (200) in the list. Not sure what could be problem.
Is it due the removal of value in the dict.

How to resolve this. Do we need to do copy to another object and remove from it.

Comment: The problem is you are mutating the list in place.

Comment: Also, there is no reason to call `mydict.get` in the inner loop; you already *have* a reference to that list, `ids`.

Comment: Also, a `continue` at the end of a loop is not necessary.

Comment: also why write `if not id > 1000:` when you can write `if id <= 1000:`? To keep the headache going?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reliably modify a list over which you are iterating. Simply filter the list, then replace it with the filtered copy.

```
for emp, ids in mydict.iteritems():
    print "Emp:", emp
    new_ids = []
    for id in ids:
        print "Id", id
        if id > 1000:
            new_ids.append(id)
    my_dict[emp] = new_ids
```

If you aren't printing each id as you see it, you can replace the inner loop with a single call to `filter`:

```
for emp, ids in my_dict.iteritems():
    my_dict[emp] = [id for id in ids if id > 1000]
    # my_dict[emp] = filter(lambda x: x > 1000, ids)
```

You could even rebuild the entire `dict` from scratch:

```
my_dict = {emp: [id for id in ids if id > 1000] for emp, ids in my_dict.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should not remove element during iteration

```
my_dict={'emp_id': [100, 200, 10000]}
new_dict={ emp:[ele for ele in ids if ele <= 1000] for emp,ids in my_dict.iteritems() }
{'emp_id': [100, 200]}
```

Comment: Why doesn't the 10000 appear in the resulting `dict`?

Answer (score -1):

It's not good to modify my_dict during iteration.

If you want to just print: not (id > 1000), then remove my_dict.get(emp).remove(id).

Otherwise, remove first then print.